# Шаблон проектирования для очереди

Tags: шаблоны, php, шаблоны-проектирования

Что нужно реализовать: сформировать очередь задач и выполнить их.

Задачи могут быть разным. Характеризуются классом, методом и параметрами для этого метода. Например, задача("архиватор", "добавить-файл-в-архив", "имя-файла-архива, имя-файла").

Выполнение может быть прервано и затем продолжено, например, отведенное время на итерацию закончилось и нужно перезапуститься.

Какие шаблоны проектирования посоветуете посмотреть?

Comment: почему вы считаете, что вам необходим именно шаблон проектирования?

Comment: Не хочу изобретать велосипед и первое о чем подумал это шаблоны

Comment: Подумайте о чем нибудь более приземленном, например паре файлов.

--

В конец одного файла записываются новые строки (каждая строка это команда, что нужно делать и ее аргументы). Собственно это очередь, если обращаться к высокому.

Второй файл - это одно число - номер строки в файле-очереди, которую  обработчик запустил на выполнение.

Далее - ps, grep и т.п. Вам в руки.

Comment: Для реализации "задач" остановлюсь на шаблоне "command"

Answer (score 6):

Смысл очередей сводиться к простому обмену сообщений между процессами. То есть один процесс отправляет сообщение с данными о задании, а другой ждет сообщение, и как только оно поступает - выполняет задание, которое описано в сообщении. После этого может отправить сообщение первому процессу о том, что задание выполнено. Обычно есть клиент, сервер и воркер. Клиент добавляет задание, сервер получает его и отдает нужному воркеру, который его выполняет. Для организации такого обмена существует много решений, среди которых: Gearman, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Amazon SQS (облачный сервис очередей).

Использую Gearman на своих проектах. Клиент может добавить задание для выполнения как в фоновом режиме, так и ждать его выполнение и отслеживать статус. По gearman много информации в интернете, и существуют клиенты практически для всех популярных языков программирования. Пока нареканий не было, работает очень быстро и стабильно.

Для ознакомления с gearman статья на [Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142210/).

Решений для организации очередей достаточно. Что использовать - скорее дело вкуса. У всего есть свои плюсы и минусы. Гуглите в сторону "Queue", "Message Queue". Если остановитесь на gearman смогу помочь в установке и настройке.

[Статьи на эту тему на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=queue).

Comment: Артем, опять ты со своими готовыми решениями!)) Пусть люди потренируются, поизобретают велосипеды :))) Это же так интересно! :)
К тому же тот же gearman никак не позволяет влиять на очередь задач. Разве что некое подобие приоритета...
/* Если что, этот комментарий - ирония */

Comment: Ну над этими "готовыми" решениями тоже придется немного попотеть ) У германа очередь можно хранить в БД, поэтому кое-как управлять ею можно.

Comment: А шаблон проектирования вроде как Producer/Customer называется.
Вот хорошее видео на эту тему. Раскрывает как суть так и проблемы, с которыми придется столкнуться.
Часть 1 - http://video.yandex.ua/users/xpinjection/view/240/
Часть 2 - http://video.yandex.ua/users/xpinjection/view/241/
Часть 3 - http://video.yandex.ua/users/xpinjection/view/243/
Часть 4 - http://video.yandex.ua/users/xpinjection/view/242/